# Default Value is SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have a Parameter in my SSRS report which is the Financial Year. I also have one for the Financial Period. Both of these have a start and end date.

For both parameters I want the report to default to the current year and period off of today's date.

So example for Parameter Financial Year I have the following fields - 
Year = 2015, 2016, 2017
StartDate
EndDate

So as today's date is 27/07/2016 and that is between the start and end date of 2016 I would want that to come back as the default.

Similar to the Period. For that I have the following fields - 
Financial Period = 201601,201602..and so on
Start Date
End Date

As todays date falls between the start and end date of 2001617, it is that period that I would want to be defaulted.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get the current year you can use:

```
=Today.Year
```

For the period you can use this:

```
=Today.Year & format(Today,"MM")
```

If your period column is a `int` column you can use:

```
=CINT(Today.Year & format(Today,"MM"))
```

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Thanks but, that's not worked.  So as an example - for the year I have in the Data Set -Description, Year , Start Date and End Date. I want an expression to look at this DataSet and the Start Date and End Date and default to the Year which in my data set is in the following format - Weekly2015, or Monthly2016. This is a concatenation of the Description and Year. Thanks

Comment: @ikilledbill, Specify what is the default value you want for both parameters, it is not clear at all. My answer is based on this statement in your question: __For both parameters I want the report to default to the current year and period off of today's date__.

Comment: So I have two Rent Calendars - Weekly and Monthly.  This is a parameter. Both of these are defaulted.I then have another parameter called Financial Year. As each Rent Calendar has a Year attached I have a cascading parameter to only show those linked to the Rent Calendar in question. So as an example Monthly has - Monthly2015, Monthly2016 and Monthly2017. Weekly has -Weekly2015, Weekly2016.

Comment: As I have included the start and end dates of those years in my data set I wanted to be able for the default value to say-ok I'm the 27/07/2016 - that is between the start and end date of two years - Monthly2016 and Weekly2016 and set them both to defaults Hope that's a bit clearer

Comment: @ikilledbill, Why do you want to compare the current date against your dataset if it will always match Weekly2016 and Monthly2016 default values for your parameters? I think it is not clear for me yet.

Comment: It won't always match Weekly 2016. Weeky2016 has a Start Date of 01-04-2016 - EndDate of 31-03-2017. If you are to run the report in 01-04-2017, this will default to Weekly2017 as that will be the Financial year that that date falls between.